# netbeans doesn't start after installing jdk 8

Tags: netbeans, config, java

I just uninstalled jdk7 update25 and installed jdk8 instead. I've modified the following line `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0"` in etc/netbeans.conf but Netbeans still doesn't start. I even rebooted my computer but I've always the same problem.
My version of netbeans is 7.2.1.

---

#### Solved

Solution is to install JDK_7_025 back and to set JDK8 in the project only.

Comment: [probably Netbeans sites are better place for searching](https://netbeans.org/search_result.html?cx=006102455337629464213%3Amt38ytkbuak&cof=FORID%3A11&q=java8&x=0&y=0)

Comment: doesn't help either :(

Comment: I just uninstalled jdk7 update25 and installed jdk8 instead. installer is based on selected JDK, (never tried) to install JDK_7_025 back and to set JDK8 in project only